# Is it possible to do model-first ORM mapping with ServiceStack and OrmLite?

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I'm just discovering ServiceStack for the first time this weekend and I find it completely amazing. As such, I'm already in the process of converting all of my projects over to it. Then I ran into a small snag.

I can't find any documentation that mentions using OrmLite starting with the database first and then mapping an existing schema into POCOs.

I've found plenty of material on code-first, but nothing on model-first.

Is there a way to use OrmLiite taking a model-first approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OrmLite is primarily a code-first ORM, but if you want to start with an existing database you would just create a POCO with properties that maps 1:1 to an existing Table and columns.

It's trivial to infer a POCO manually, but if you want some code-gen tool to help do this, OrmLite includes a [couple of T4 scripts you could use instead](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/tree/master/src/T4).